# How do I change the working directory of a spark master

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sparksession which I currently create like so:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("myapp").getOrCreate()
```

I would like to set the working directory of the spark master. It is currently using /tmp and I would like to use something else.

I noticed there is a config(..) option, could I do something like:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("myapp").config("option", "value").getOrCreate()
```

Is there a list of options that are available somewhere? Should it be done in a different way?

Comment: You may check `spark.local.dir` https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html#application-properties

Comment: Thanks - if you write that as an answer - I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `spark.local.dir` to the custom folder or set env variable `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS`.
By default, it uses `/tmp`

More details here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html#application-properties

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that I can set the environment variable `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` to do that, but I would prefer it if I could do it programatically.

Comment: `import os; os.env["SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS"] = "new/path/for/spark"`